# Lambda not sending message to SQS destination - event source mapping

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, amazon-kinesis

I have a lambda function that is triggered by a Kinesis data stream, `my-stream`. I would like to store failed records' metadata in an SQS queue. I have therefore created an SQS queue `my-destination-queue`, with both redrive policy and dead-letter queue disabled, and I have then added this queue destination to my lambda function with the following configuration:

```
Source: Event source mapping invocation
Event source mapping: stream/my-stream
Condition: On failure
Destination type: SQS queue
Destination: my-destination-queue
```

I see that lambda is correctly processing the stream records, and that some of them are failing, but nothing is being sent to the SQS queue. However, the lambda execution role does have `sqs:SendMessage` permission on all resources.

I have tested this setup first with a test data stream I created `stream-test`. If I manually put records to this stream and lambda fails to process them, their metadata is correctly sent to the destination queue, but when I try this with `my-stream` it does not work.

I am putting records to `stream-test` as follows:

```
aws kinesis put-record --stream-name stream-test --partition-key 123 --cli-binary-format raw-in-base64-out --data '{"Records": [{"kinesis":{"data":{}}}]}' --profile my-profile
```

What is the difference causing lambda not to write in `my-stream`?